# Unexpected token else

Tags: token, if

```
$("#crn").click(function(){
    if ($("#ans1").val()!=""&&$("#ans2").val()!=""&&$("#ans3").val()!=""&&$("#ans4").val()!=""&&$("#cor").val()!=""&&$("#que").val()!=""){
            var c1=0;
            var c2=0;
            var c3=0;
            var c4=0;

        if($("#cor1").val()=="1"){ 
            c1=1
        };
        else if($(".cor2").val()=="2") {
            c2=1
        };
        else if($("#cor3").val()=="3") {
            c3=1
        };
        else if($("#cor4").val()=="4") {
            c4=1
        };

        newviktor.push({
            number: 0,
            question: $("#que").val(),
            answers: [
                {
                    number: 1,
                    correct: c1,
                    answer: $("#ans1").val()
                },
                {
                    number: 2,
                    correct: c2,
                    answer: $("#ans2").val()
                },
                {
                    number: 3,
                    correct: c3,
                    answer: $("#ans3").val()
                },
                {
                    number: 4,
                    correct: c4,
                    answer: $("#ans4").val()
                }
            ]
        });

        alert("Вопрос добавлен к вашей викторине");
        $("#ans1").val("");
        $("#ans2").val("");
        $("#ans3").val("");
        $("#ans4").val("");
        $("#cor").val("");
        $("#que").val("");

    }
});
```

Comment: После `if{ .... }; else` на это и получаете ошибку. `;` не надо ставить перед `else`

Answer (score 1):

Тут надо убрать лишние `;` перед `else` и *желательно* поставить их после утверждений присваивания

```
if($("#cor1").val()=="1"){ 
    c1=1;
}
else if($(".cor2").val()=="2") {
    c2=1;
}
else if($("#cor3").val()=="3") {
    c3=1;
}
else if($("#cor4").val()=="4") {
    c4=1;
}
```